ValueError: Input X contains NaN. SVR does not accept missing values encoded as NaN natively
I use SVR to predict my data
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
import csv
from math import sqrt
from scipy import stats
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

filepath = '/content/drive/MyDrive/TESIS/DATA/'

pilihankolom = 35

X = pd.read_csv(filepath+'Data_Radiomic.csv').to_numpy()
Y = pd.read_csv(filepath+'Data_Dosiomic.csv', usecols=[pilihankolom])
print(X.shape)
Y_label = str(Y.columns)
Y = Y.to_numpy()

(187, 98)

model=SVR(kernel='rbf', C=10, epsilon=0.01)
kf = KFold(n_splits=4)

X_training, X_testing, Y_training, Y_testing = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
print(X_training.shape, X_testing.shape)

(149, 98) (38, 98)

prediction = []
mse_set = []
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X_training):
  print(train_index, test_index)
  X_train, X_test = X_training[train_index], X_training[test_index]
  Y_train, Y_test = Y_training[train_index], Y_training[test_index]
  model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
  mse_set.append(mean_squared_error(Y_test, Y_pred))
  prediction.extend(Y_pred)

this is the result
[ 38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55
56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73
74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91
92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109
110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127
128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145
146 147 148] [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37]
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-98eca0acb6ac> in <cell line: 3>()
      5   X_train, X_test = X_training[train_index], X_training[test_index]
      6   Y_train, Y_test = Y_training[train_index], Y_training[test_index]
----> 7   model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
      8   Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
      9   mse_set.append(mean_squared_error(Y_test, Y_pred))

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/_base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    190             check_consistent_length(X, y)
    191         else:
--> 192             X, y = self._validate_data(
    193                 X,
    194                 y,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    582                 y = check_array(y, input_name="y", **check_y_params)
    583             else:
--> 584                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    585             out = X, y
    586 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
   1104         )
   1105 
-> 1106     X = check_array(
   1107         X,
   1108         accept_sparse=accept_sparse,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
    919 
    920         if force_all_finite:
--> 921             _assert_all_finite(
    922                 array,
    923                 input_name=input_name,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype, estimator_name, input_name)
    159                 "#estimators-that-handle-nan-values"
    160             )
--> 161         raise ValueError(msg_err)
    162 
    163 

ValueError: Input X contains NaN.
SVR does not accept missing values encoded as NaN natively. For supervised learning, you might want to consider sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier and Regressor which accept missing values encoded as NaNs natively. Alternatively, it is possible to preprocess the data, for instance by using an imputer transformer in a pipeline or drop samples with missing values. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html You can find a list of all estimators that handle NaN values at the following page: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#estimators-that-handle-nan-values
please  any advice to solve this error

What about the error message's suggestions don't you understand/not want to implement?

Your input data contains invalid/missing values (NaNs or "not a number"). Three main options:

Use an estimator that can handle invalid values, like HistGradientBoostingRegressor. The one you're using (SVM) will error with NaNs, like most sklearn estimators. See here for a list of estimators that handle NaN values.
If you want to use SVR, you could simply drop the NaNs from your dataset before giving it to the SVR. You should consider whether it's okay to simply discard any sample/row that has one or more missing values.
As an alternative to dropping the rows with NaNs, you could replace them using SimpleImputer. That replaces NaNs with a number, and you can then supply the cleaned dataset to SVR. SimpleImputer is a good place to start, and here is more about imputation.

